# Meaning of "off to its fastest start"

Tags: phrase-meaning

On **CNBC**, there is [this article](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/05/11/gold-demand-is-off-to-its-fastest-start-ever-in-2016.html) titled:

> "Gold demand is off to its fastest start ever in 2016"

I am not sure what "off to its fastest start" is supposed to mean.

Does it mean that demand is decreasing now after a strong start (but shouldn't  in that case be "off from its fastest start") or does it mean that demand is still increasing  despite a strong start?

Is "***off to something***" an idiomatic expression? I could not find a dictionary entry with that reference.

Thanks

Comment: The most usual variant is 'off to a good start'; 'off to a fast start' is also common. The idiom is reasonably amenable to variation, but suitable adjectives are of course necessary. [Get] off to a bad / poor / slow / wobbly / steady /  reasonable /  early ... start. ?Off to an unexpected start ... /  */?Off to a false start / *We got off to a start at once.

Answer (score 2):

I think this means that the difference in the price of gold at the time of writing compared to the price at the start of the year is higher than in any previous year. Whether this is percentage growth or absolute isn't specified.

From personal experience the idiomatic use comprises the entire phrase "`<subject>` is off to it's `<superlative adjective>` ever" and is typically heard in sporting commentary - not known for it's grammatical correctness! The phrase probably derives from the idiomatic "He's off to a slow start" - where the off is used as in "Off (their marks)". You often hear commentators saying "And they're off!" at the start of the race - where a starter might have said: "On your marks, get set, go!".

Also, one typically "sets off" on a journey.

Comment: Thanks, so you are saying that it is an idiomatic "colloquial" expression used in sports?  So "off to" means higher than here, correct?

Comment: Yes, but again, this isn't a scientific response, just personal experience. Certainly worth waiting for other opinions!

Answer (score 2):

"off to" means "to move from the current, or starting, position to somewhere else".  Eg "We're off to the park" means "We're leaving here to go to the park".

"start" can be a noun, describing how something started.

So, "is off to it's fastest start" could be translated as

"Is in the process of leaving its starting position, and on this occassion it has moved more quickly from this position than it has ever done before".

"Off to a fast start" is indeed a sporting expression, usually used in races (horse and human).